# How to create a jupyterhub widget as an object?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

Using jupyterlab 1.1.4 I want to create an object that displays a widget and that simplifies the definition of the widgets and callback functions. In a first cell I create and start the instance:

```
from ipywidgets import FileUpload
from ipywidgets import widgets
from IPython.display import display

class MyWidget():
    def __init__(self):
        self.output = widgets.Output()
        self.upload = FileUpload(description='Choose file')
        self.upload_filename = None
        self.upload.observe(self.upload_file, names=['value'])
        display(self.upload, self.output)

    @output.capture()
    def upload_file(self, args):
        self.upload_filename = list(args['new'].keys())[0]
        print("File selected: {}".format(self.upload_filename))

w = MyWidget()
```

When running this cell it shows a `FileUpload` button, and when I click on it I can choose a file. But when I do so, I expect to see some output (as I print the selected filename). But there is no output.

What am I doing wrong? How to do it correctly?

I even can go farther and change the `upload_file` method like the following:

```
    @output.capture()
    def upload_file(self, args):
        a=1/0
        self.upload_filename = list(args['new'].keys())[0]
        print("File selected: {}".format(self.upload_filename))
```

which contains an obvious error! But when I run the cell and choose a file, I do not see any error output.

How to fix this?